# How can I remove focus border with vendor prefix?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a responsive website that I'm building using Bootstrap 4 and I can't find the way to remove all outlines when clickable elements are clicked.  This is what I have so far but won't work:

```
*,
*:focus {
   outline: none !important;
   -webkit-outline: none !important;
   -moz-outline: none !important;
   -ms-outline: none !important;
   -o-outline: none !important;
}
```

I don't want to use `border: none` because I do use borders in my design.

Here's a screenshot of the site on my mobile phone (iPhone XR) in Chrome:
[image]

Comment: According to my understanding, border and outline are different things. If you are looking to remove borders, you must set borders to none, removing outline wont work

Comment: I'd caution anyone who wants to remove focus outlines from their elements to make sure that you have some *other* indicator of what element has focus. The outline (or some other indicator) is crucial for accessibility. If you are using the keyboard, you need that indicator to know which element has focus so you know how to use the page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, we need more HTML and CSS to work with. But as far as I know bootstrap uses `box-shoadw` to add this border like effect.

So just override the `box-shadow` they added and you should be good to go.

example:

```css
/* CSS from bootstrap */

.form-control:focus {
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #80bdff;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, .25);
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

If removing the `box-shadow` didn't work please let me know in a comment.